# Main methods used to predict functional annotations in GO

Tags: bioinformatics

Can someone provide me some information about the main method used to predict the *inferred electronic annotations* in Gene Ontology?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I suspect that it’s better suited on [biostars.org](http://www.biostars.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i'll try there. If i obtain answers i will re-post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most common source of electronic annotations comes from analysis of peptide sequences.  A collection of InterPro to GO mappings were created manually and can generate GO annotations.  DNA binding domains of transcription factors would be given "DNA binding" GO annotations say.

This method has its flaws - if the domain detected has evolved away from the function used for the Interpro to GO listing, there is a potential for error in this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer the [IEA documentation](http://www.geneontology.org/GO.evidence.shtml#iea) maintained by GO consortium to get an idea about the automatically assigned evidence codes using IEA. Also please note that IEA is different from [Computational Analysis Evidence Codes](http://www.geneontology.org/GO.evidence.shtml#computational)

- ISS: Inferred from Sequence or Structural Similarity
- ISO: Inferred from Sequence Orthology
- ISA: Inferred from Sequence Alignment
- ISM: Inferred from Sequence Model
- IGC: Inferred from Genomic Context
- IBA: Inferred from Biological aspect of Ancestor
- IBD: Inferred from Biological aspect of Descendant
- IKR: Inferred from Key Residues
- IRD: Inferred from Rapid Divergence
- RCA: inferred from Reviewed Computational Analysis